# Complex random variable proof: $|\mathbb EX| \leq \mathbb E |X|$

Tags: statistics, complex-numbers, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X = Y + iZ$ be a complex random variable.

How can we prove

$$|\mathbb EX| \leq \mathbb E |X|$$

I understand why this relationship should hold, but I can't prove it in a mathematically rigorous manner.

Comment: **Hint :** That's a Jensen Inequality look-alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put
$$ z = \mathbb{E} X, $$
and find a complex number $\alpha$ of unit length such that
$$ |z| = z\alpha. $$
This is esentially just the polar decomposition of a complex number.
Then
$$ |z| = z\alpha = \mathbb{E} (\alpha X) = \text{Re } \mathbb{E} (\alpha X) = \mathbb{E} (\text{Re} (\alpha X)) \leq \mathbb{E} |\alpha X| = \mathbb{E} |X|, $$
where the third sign of equality holds since the left-hand side is a real number, and the inequality holds since
$$ \text{Re }\zeta \leq \sqrt{(\text{Re }\zeta)^2} \leq \sqrt{(\text{Re }\zeta)^2+(\text{Im }\zeta)^2} = |\zeta|, $$
for any complex $\zeta$.

Comment: $ z\alpha = \mathbb{E} (X) * \alpha = \mathbb{E} (\alpha X)$

Just so I am understanding it correctly, the second equality holds because $\alpha$ is constant sinze  $z$ is constant?

Comment: @q126y Indeed, $z$ and $\alpha$ are fixed!

Answer (score 0):

By linearity of expectation, $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y+iZ]=\mathbb{E}[Y]+i\mathbb{E}[Z]$. Further, the function $g(y,z)=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ is convex. Hence, by Jensen inequality

$$\mathbb{E}[g(y,z)] \ge g(\mathbb{E}[(y,z)])$$

or

$$\mathbb{E}(|X|) \ge g(\mathbb{E}(y,z))=|\mathbb{E}[X]|$$